# What is the availability of NSNotFound?

Tags: ios, foundation, code-documentation

This in-Xcode documentation for `NSNotFound` is quite confusing:

[image]

It says "Available in iOS 2.0 through 8.4" and "Availability: iOS 8.1 to 8.0". So... **Is it available before 8.0? Or in 9.0+? Also, what's going on here, if it is?**

Comment: Ever found out? Or just tried see how it behaves on different versions? The current documentation now says `Availability (8.0 to 8.0)`.

Comment: @Alex I haven't. It seems it's working fine in at least iOS 7.2 to 9.2.1, since that's who our app supports.

Comment: Seems to work fine for me as well from iOS 7.0 to 9.2.1. Weird.

Comment: I'd recommend submitting a documentation bug to [Apple](http://bugreport.apple.com) .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Insert `availabilityOfNSNotFound == NSNotFound` joke here.

---

At some point when Apple was pushing mandatory 64-bit device support (iOS 8.4 SDK?), the declaration of `NSNotFound` was changed from:

```
enum {NSNotFound = NSIntegerMax};
```

to

```
static const NSInteger NSNotFound = NSIntegerMax;
```

You can verify this in `<Foundation/NSObjCRuntime.h>`.

The documentation was never changed, so the availability of the `enum` `NSNotFound` is no longer in the SDK.  But as of iOS 9 and above, the `static const NSInteger` `NSNotFound` is available.

Although I cannot answer the true availability of `NSNotFound` since I don't work for Apple (as a developer I think it's safe to use in all iOS versions since 2.0, or else a lot of Foundation classes would break since they can return `NSNotFound`), you can check to see if the memory location for `NSNotFound` is NULL:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wtautological-compare"
BOOL found = (&NSNotFound != NULL);
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
if (found) {
    NSLog(@"meh");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I realized that `NSNotFound` is a static constant, and so it shouldn't matter what OS the device has, as the value *shouldn't* change after compilation.

To confirm this, I made the simplest file I could and looked at its compiled assembly (without optimizations):

**Left:** original C source code. **Right:** LLVM assembly output.

[image: An illustration showing NSNotFound is replaced with its absolute value at compile time]

As you can see, `NSNotFound` is replaced with its absolute value, in this case `0x7fffffffffffffff` since this is a 64-bit compilation. For 32-bit compilations, it would be `0x7fffffff`.

This is awesome. It means that, **as long as it compiles, it will work** (assuming Apple never changes the value of `NSNotFound`)!

While this doesn't explain the strange documentation, it does provide some reassurance that it should work on all versions of iOS.

Comment: You really shouldn't use a hardcoded value instead of the constant.  The constant is exposed like this for a reason!  Additionally, the value is assigned to `NSIntegerMax`, which expands to `LONG_MAX`, which could potentially be platform-dependent.

Comment: @JAL I think you're misunderstanding me. I'm using the constant! The left pane is the C code, and the right pane is the assembly output of the compiler.

Comment: I'm not misunderstanding you.  I just saying it's not safe to use either constant.

Comment: @JAL But you said "You really shouldn't use a hardcoded value instead of a constant." I'm not; I'm using the constant.

Comment: I see, you're referring to the value after compilation.