# What is NSNotFound exactly?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

How much is NSNotFound exactly?

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33419473/what-is-the-availability-of-nsnotfound) post, it's NSIntegerMax.(Although I can't find  on iOS 9.3 on XCode.)

So in 64 bits system, it should be 2^64-1 or 2^63-1?
I think it's 2^64-1 but a post said it's 2^63-1, which one correct?

Comment: Is the actual value important? It's not something you save, it's something that you compare against.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is 2^63-1. In a 64 bit number the least significant bit is 2^0 and the most significant is 2^63 making a total of 64 bits

Comment: I just understood now, it's the max number in signed integer, not unsigned integer. So that 2^0 doesn't mean 0 or 1, it actually means -2^63.

Comment: No, there are 64 bits. 2^0 is the first bit and 2^63 is the 64th bit. Think of an array with 64 elements; array[0] is the first element and array[63] is the 64th element. In a signed integer the maximum value that can be represented is 2^63-1 and the smallest is -2^63+1  In an unsigned the largest value is 2^64-1

Answer (score 3):

This is how it's defined in `Foundation/NSObjCRunTime.h`:

```
static const NSInteger NSNotFound = NSIntegerMax;
```

So on 32-bit devices it's `2^31 - 1`, on 64-bit devices it is `2^63 - 1`. In Swift, you can find the constant as `Int.max`